# simple fields plugin custom query

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, php, plugin-simple-fields

I have a collection of posts for families.  I'm using the simple fields plugin for handle members of the family. Is there a simple way to query posts based on values from the custom fields created by the simple fields plugin.

I see the meta keys in the admin:

```
_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_1_numInSet_0
_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_2_numInSet_0
_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_3_numInSet_0

_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_1_numInSet_1
_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_2_numInSet_1
_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_3_numInSet_1
```

where fieldID_1 is a dropdown for year (1950-2010), 
fieldID_2 is a dropdown for gender (male or female) 
fieldID_3 is a textfield for name

How would I query to get all posts where gender is 'male' and ordered by year?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

There are numInSet_N values.  Some might have 0, others 10 or more.

The simple fields plugin creates generic values for each key. For example,     _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_1_numInSet_0 is a dropdown for year and has the following key values:

```
dropdown_num_2
dropdown_num_3
dropdown_num_4
...
dropdown_num_62
```

Where dropdown_num_2 is actually 1950, dropdown_num_3 is 1951 and so forth.

The same is true for the gender dropdown, _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_2_numInSet_0, which has the following key values:

```
dropdown_num_2
dropdown_num_3
```

Where dropdown_num_2 is actually 'male', dropdown_num_3 is 'female'.

So the query to get all posts where gender is 'male' and ordered by year would need to check _simple_fields_fieldGroupID_6_fieldID_2_numInSet_N == 'dropdown_num_2' and ORDER BY the year of all matched posts.

Comment: @jaysonp - You show two sets of keys. Are there many sets of those keys? I'm trying to understand  the `0` and `1` in `numInSet_0` and `numInSet_1`. Are there many `numInSet_N` or just those two? Also, what are the values of those keys?

Comment: Hey Mike, I updated the post to help clarify.

Comment: Is that related to a specific plugin or have you coded that on your own? Do you have access to the underlying sourcecode? This looks like pretty individual problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, way late, but I found this looking for the answer myself before solving it, so I'll post for others in my boat, as I'm sure the OP sorted this by now. ;)

Use `"meta_key"` and `"meta_value"` in your query after taking a look at "post_meta" in your database to figure out what the simple fields plugin created, like the OP did above. The query I needed which is posted below grabs posts from 3 different post types (2 custom) where the simple field I added: "feature in homepage slider" has a dropdown value of yes (`meta_value: dropdown_num_3`).

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => '10', 
        'post_type' => array('filmp', 'corp', 'post'), 
        'meta_key' => '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_1_fieldID_3_numInSet_0', 
        'meta_value' => 'dropdown_num_3'
    )
);
```